# Cmake: линк библиотеки лежащий в отдельной папке

Tags: c++, c, lib, cmake, link

Здравствуйте! Есть проект, который выглядит примерно вот так:

```
engine/CMakeLists.txt
engine/libs/SOIL/libSOIL.a
```

Как можно подключить эту библиотеку (libSOIL.a) к моему проекту в `CMakeLists.txt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так

```
add_executable(main main.c)
target_link_libraries(main ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/SOIL/libSOIL.a)
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное